# Hyperref chapter link anchors in two column mode

Tags: hyperref, two-column, links

I am using the `hyperref` package to generate bookmarks and links for the table of contents. However, when rendering documents in two column mode the chapter link anchors are placed below the actual chapter title, resulting in the view starting below the chapter heading upon using any of these links/bookmarks. Is there a way to fix this?

I am using the koma-script `scrreprt` class, however the problem appears with the normal report class as well.

Example:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{First chapter}
\lipsum
\chapter{Second chapter}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may not be an ideal solution, but it works.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{First}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\lipsum[1-6]
\end{multicols}

\chapter{Second}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\lipsum[7-12]
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```