# Hyperref chapter in twocolumn mode (without using multicols)

Tags: hyperref, chapters, two-column

I'm using the scrreprt class in twocolumn mode with hyperref:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[twocolumn]{geometry}
\usepackage{hyperref}


\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{This is a chapter}

\chapter{Chapter TWOOO}

\end{document}
```

My problem is that the links in the table of contents do not point to the chapter heading, a common bug as in multiple questions, particularly [Hyperref chapter link anchors in two column mode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/222564/hyperref-chapter-link-anchors-in-two-column-mode). The accepted answer there uses multicols in each chapter, which is functional but requires the twocolumn mode to be implemented via a `multicol` environment.

This is unacceptable to me as it seems to violate separation of form and content and can't be supplied to a `.cls`. Is there a way to have the hyperref links to chapters link to the heading? I would be happy with the chapter linking to the chapter heading's *page* if not the exact position of the chapter heading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer defines a new command `\Chapter` which links entries in the contents with chapter pages using `navigator` rather than `hyperref`.

Used in overly creative ways, this will certainly break things. Used in fairly standard ways, however, I think it may be helpful.

## ***Caveat emptor...***

By default, loading `navigator` has no effect on your document (as far as I can tell). However, the macro `\Chapter` demonstrates that it is possible, at least in theory, to use the package to set up links from the contents to the page on which the chapter begins in such a way that the chapter title is shown. Even though the anchor is placed *after* the chapter heading, it is configured so that the link shows the top part of the page i.e. content which is *before* the anchor in the source.

## Syntax

```
\Chapter[short title]{title}
\Chapter*[short title]{title}
```

- `\Chapter[]{}` feeds its arguments to KOMA's `\chapter[]{}` command and creates an anchor for the link from the contents.
- `\Chapter*[]{}` feeds its arguments to KOMA's `\addchap[]{}` command and creates an anchor for the link from the contents. It uses a new counter to ensure unique names for the anchors created in this way.

There is no equivalent of KOMA's `\addchap*{}` because the star in `\Chapter*[]{}` is being used to determine whether to use `\chapter[]{}` or `\addchap[]{}` in the first place. If you wanted to mirror KOMA's commands more exactly, you could create another command (e.g. `\AddChap*[]{}`) instead. However, it seems from your comments that you are using `\chapter*{}` and so I've stuck with a version of that.

SCLFME (Somewhat Crude Likely Fragile Minimal Example):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twocolumn]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{navigator,xparse,kantlipsum}
\newcounter{unnumberedchapter}
\setcounter{unnumberedchapter}{0}
\NewDocumentCommand \Chapter { s o m }{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
    \stepcounter{unnumberedchapter}%
    \IfValueTF{#2}{%
      \addchap[\protect\jumplink{nonoch\theunnumberedchapter}{#2}]{#3}%
      \outline[fit=fitv]{1}[nonoch\theunnumberedchapter]{#3}%
    }{%
      \addchap[\protect\jumplink{nonoch\theunnumberedchapter}{#3}]{#3}%
      \outline[fit=fitv]{1}[nonoch\theunnumberedchapter]{#3}%
    }%
  }{%
    \IfValueTF{#2}{%
      \chapter[\protect\jumplink{ch\thechapter}{#2}]{#3}%
      \outline[fit=fitv]{1}[ch\thechapter]{#3}%
    }{%
      \chapter[\protect\jumplink{ch\thechapter}{#3}]{#3}%
      \outline[fit=fitv]{1}[ch\thechapter]{#3}%
    }%
  }%
}
\pagestyle{headings}

\begin{document}
  \tableofcontents

  \Chapter*{Introduction}
  \kant[1-4]

  \Chapter*[Another]{Another Introduction}
  \kant[5-7]

  \Chapter[Shorter]{This is a chapter}
  \kant[8-12]

  \Chapter{Chapter TWOOO}
  \kant[13-17]

  \Chapter*{Epilogue}
  \kant[18-20]

\end{document}
```

Note that if you want a chapter which does not appear in the contents, you can, of course, simply use `\chapter*{}` in the usual way.

Comment: (Ignore previous comment.) The only problem I foresee is if I want a starred chapter to appear in the table of contents. Right now I'm using `\chapter*{Intro}\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Intro}`. Would I have to manually edit the table of contents for this to happen? I tried `\addcontentsline{toc}{Chapter}{Intro}` (capital `C`) but that produced an error.

Comment: @Hugh That is doable but it will have to be later. It is already too late (early) here and my brain can't figure out anything. I'll try to polish it a bit when it (brain) has had some sleep ;).

Comment: @Hugh Please see edited answer. This is not very sophisticated but it is a bit more so than my earlier version!

Comment: @Hugh Is this working for you? Or have you found a different solution?

Comment: This is working, but I think the alternative solution works better (and answers the question I originally asked). What made you choose `navigator` over `hyperref`?

Comment: Accepted to give 2nd place credit. :)

Comment: @Hugh You don't need to give 2nd place credit! I really just tried `navigator` because I knew it handles the links differently from `hyperref` and I thought it might happen to work better. I tried it and it did, so I posted the solution. But I figured that switching to `navigator` might well create other complications in part because it does not do as much out-of-the-box for you automatically in terms of creating links, whereas `hyperref` does a lot either by default or with a few package options. So I was curious whether it worked in a larger document. (I've never used `navigator` before.)

Answer (score 1):

The following solution inserts a new hyper target (an internal document link) as part of the chapter format setting.

The first step is to insert the hyper target:

```
% Add extra hyper target for chapter: chapter..\thechapter
\renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{%
  \mbox{\raisebox{25pt}[0pt][0pt]{\hypertarget{chapter..\thechapter}{}}% Add 
    \chapappifchapterprefix{\nobreakspace}\thechapter\autodot\enskip}%
}
```

Above we insert a target named `chapter..\thechapter`, raised by 25pt (an appropriate height, without affecting any vertical positioning). This target is synonymous with the traditional target `chapter.\thechapter`.

The second step is to adjust the hyper link to point to this new hyper target *only* when you're calling `\chapter`. For this we patch `\addcontentsline`:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
% Update \addcontentsline to jump to new hyper target _only_ if \chapter is used
\patchcmd{\addcontentsline}% <cmd>
  {\Hy@writebookmark}% <search>
  {\ifnum\pdfstrcmp{chapter}{#2}=0 % Chapter mark
     \edef\@currentHref{chapter..\thechapter}%
   \fi
   \Hy@writebookmark}% <replace>
  {}{}% <success><failure>
\makeatother
```

The above patch inserts a conditional to check whether you've used `\chapter` or not (via a `\pdfstrcmp` string comparison - requires e-TeX). If you are using `\chapter`, then `\@currentHref` is updated to point to the new hyper target `chapter..\thechapter`. This is done just before the bookmark and ToC-related entry is placed.

Here is a complete usage and minimal example:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{hyperref,lipsum,etoolbox}

% Add extra hyper target for chapter: chapter..\thechapter
\renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{%
  \mbox{\raisebox{25pt}[0pt][0pt]{\hypertarget{chapter..\thechapter}{}}% Add 
    \chapappifchapterprefix{\nobreakspace}\thechapter\autodot\enskip}%
}
\makeatletter
% Update \addcontentsline to jump to new hyper target _only_ if \chapter is used
\patchcmd{\addcontentsline}% <cmd>
  {\Hy@writebookmark}% <search>
  {\ifnum\pdfstrcmp{chapter}{#2}=0 % Chapter mark
     \edef\@currentHref{chapter..\thechapter}%
   \fi
   \Hy@writebookmark}% <replace>
  {}{}% <success><failure>
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{First chapter}
\lipsum[1-10]

\chapter{Second chapter}
\lipsum[11-20]

\end{document}
```

Comment: I get the error Undefined control sequence `\scr@chapter@sectionafterskip+35pt\relax` with the line break just before `+35pt\relax`

Comment: @Hugh: [Update your distribution](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55437/5764) and try again.

Comment: Thanks. This fixes the problem but raises another one: the first line of each chapter is indented. This goes away if I comment out the line with `\@afterindentfalse` but then the links break again. Any ideas?

Comment: If it helps, the indent looks to be about an en space and it does not occur with a `\chapter*`.

Comment: `\patchcmd{\chapter}{\@afterindentfalse}{\@afterindentfalse\leavevmode}{}{}` pretty much breaks all the latex after-heading code if there is a blank line after the chapter command.

Comment: @Hugh: See my updated answer which should eliminate the problems. Hopefully...

Comment: @Werner what should I patch to solve the similar problem with \vref \cref and friends?